# Keras sequential model to Tensorflow EstimatorSpec accuracy decreases

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Having some issues converting from a Keras (keras_model_fn) over to a TF model_fn for use in Sagemaker.

The models look like this:

**Keras**

```python
def keras_model_fn(hyperparameters):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    # increase input_dim (cur 2500) as amount of words go up
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=[8], name='main_input'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(2500, 128, input_length=8))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(
        optimizer='adam',
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['acc']
    )
    return model
```

**Tensorflow**

```python
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    input_layer = tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(
        input_shape=(8,))(features[INPUT_TENSOR_NAME])
    embedding_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
        2500, 
        128, 
        input_length=8)(input_layer)
    flattened = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(embedding_layer)
    predictions = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
        NUM_CLASSES, 
        activation='softmax')(flattened)

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
            mode=mode,
            predictions={"output": predictions})

    loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(labels, predictions)
    train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.train.get_global_step(),
        learning_rate=0.001,
        optimizer="Adam")

    predictions_dict = {"output": predictions}
    eval_metric_ops = {
        "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(
            tf.cast(labels,tf.int32), predictions)
    }
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode,
        loss=loss,
        train_op=train_op,
        eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops
)
```

The training and eval data is identical. Feeding in an array of padded text sequences (length 8). With an expected output of 1/5 labels.

**The Losses**

I'm assuming the problem lies in the loss function. I can't quite figure out what the Sequential model is doing behind the scenes versus what my tensorflow model is doing.

In the Keras model, I'm getting the following loss.

```python
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 170.783
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0018957269, step = 1701 (0.586 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 164.419
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.029586311, step = 1801 (0.608 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 155.381
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0019212833, step = 1901 (0.644 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 0.0023477676.
```

In the Converted model, I'm getting the following.

```python
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 1.232958, step = 1701 (0.354 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 280.328
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 1.0923336, step = 1801 (0.357 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 291.823
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 1.4360821, step = 1901 (0.343 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 1.0532712.
```

As expected the accuracy on the Converted model (for the data it was trained on) hits around 60%. The accuracy for the Keras model is at 100%.

My question here is does everything look right in the conversion? What could I be doing different with the converted model to get similar performance?

I've started to dig around in the Keras source code to see what the model compile function is doing with targets/outputs, but was going to reach out here as well to see if anyone has a suggestion/ran into this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that you're applying two softmax activations in the TensorFlow version. Note that  [tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/softmax_cross_entropy) expects unscaled logits. You could do the following:

```
logits = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
    NUM_CLASSES)(flattened)
predictions = tf.keras.layers.Activation(
    'softmax')(logits)

loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(labels, logits)
```